# Disable application badge icon on receiving notification in ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using react-native-applozic-chat for handling chats in my react-native app. My question is there any way to prevent the app badge icon from appearing on app icon after receiving any chat notification? I want to disable it specifically in ios because it does not appear in android.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. If you are not using Push Notifications, the badge should not appear automatically. If you are using APN, than you can set to zero the applicationIconBadgeNumber property of your application derived class. Last possibility, you go to the Settings of your up and disable badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

in AppDelegate didfinishLaunched to get the the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the app badge count completely.

You can use the below setting in `ALChatmanager.m` file inside the method `ALDefaultChatViewSettings`.

```
[ALUserDefaultsHandler setUnreadCountType:0];
```

Make sure this setting is added only once in `ALChatmanager.m` file

For more information on this disabling, you can refer to the docs [here](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/ios-chat-theme-and-customization#section-enable-or-disable-the-unread-count-badge-in-an-app-icon)

Answer (score 0):

Badge number is a good option for this :

```
app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```